# Mystery: casting a GNU C label pointer to a function pointer, with inline asm to put a ret in that block. Block being optimized away?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, inline-assembly

Firstly: This code is considered to be of pure fun, please do not do anything like this in production. We will not be responsible of any harm caused to you, your company or your reindeer after compiling and executing this piece of code in any environment. The code below is not safe, not portable and is plainly dangerous. Be warned. Long post below. You were warned.

Now, after the disclaimer: Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun()
{
    return 5;
}

typedef int(*F)(void) ;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    void *ptr = &&hi;

    F f = (F)ptr;

    int  c = f();
    printf("TT: %d\n", c);

    if(c == 5) goto bye;
    //else goto bye;     /*  <---- This is the most important line. Pay attention to it */

hi:
    c = 5;
    asm volatile ("movl $5, %eax");
    asm volatile ("retq");

bye:
    return 66;
}
```

For the beginning we have the function `fun` which I have created purely for reference to get the generated assembly code.

Then we declare a function pointer `F` to functions taking no parameters and returning an int.

Then we use the not so well known GCC extension https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html to get the address of a label `hi`, and this works in clang too. Then we do something evil, we create a function pointer `F` called f and initialize it to be the label above.

Then the worst of all, we actually call this function, and assign its return value to a local variable, called `C` and the we print it out.

The following is an `if` to check if the value assigned to the `c` is actually the one we need, and if yes go to `bye` so that he application exits normally, with exit code 66. If that can be considered a normal exit code.

The next line is commented out, but I can say this is the most important line in the entire application.

The piece of code after the label `hi` is to assign 5 to the value of c, then two lines of assembly to initialize the value of `eax` to 5 and to actually return from the "function" call. As mentioned, there is a reference function, `fun` which generates the same code.

And now we compile this application, and run it on our online platform: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K6z5Yc

It generates the following assembly (with `-O1` turned on, and `O0` gives a similar result, albeit a bit more longer):

```
# else goto bye  is COMMENTED OUT
fun:
        mov     eax, 5
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "TT: %d\n"
main:
        push    rbx
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.L3
        call    rax
        mov     ebx, eax
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        cmp     ebx, 5
        je      .L4
.L3:
        movl $5, %eax
        retq
.L4:
        mov     eax, 66
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

The important lines are `mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.L3` where the `L3` corresponds to our `hi` label, and the line after that: `call    rax` which actually calls it.

And runs like:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 66
    TT: 5
```

Now, let's revisit the most important line in the application and uncomment it.

With `-O0` we get the following assembly, generated by gcc:

```
# else goto bye  is UNCOMMENTED
# even gcc -O0  "knows" hi: is unreachable.
fun:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 5
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "TT: %d\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.L4
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        call    rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 5
        nop
.L4:
        mov     eax, 66
        leave
        ret
```

and the following output:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 66
```

so, as you can see our `printf` was never called, the culprit is the line `mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.L4` where `L4` actually corresponds to our `bye` label.

And from what I can see from the generated assembly, not a piece of code from the part after `hi` was added into the generated code.

But at least the application runs and at least has some code for comparing `c` to 5.

On the other end, clang, with `O0` generates the following nightmare, which by the way crashes:

```
# else goto bye  is UNCOMMENTED
# clang -O0 also doesn't emit any instructions for the hi: block
fun:                                    # @fun
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 5
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], edi
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 24], 1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax
        call    qword ptr [rbp - 32]
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], eax
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rbp - 36]
        movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
        mov     al, 0
        call    printf
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 5
        jne     .LBB1_2
        jmp     .LBB1_3
.LBB1_2:
        jmp     .LBB1_3
.LBB1_3:
        mov     eax, 66
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "TT: %d\n"
```

If we turn on some optimization, for example `O1`, we get from gcc:

```
# else goto bye  is UNCOMMENTED
# gcc -O1
fun:
        mov     eax, 5
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "TT: %d\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.L3
        call    rax
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
.L3:
        mov     eax, 66
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

and the application crashes, which is sort of understandable. Again, the compiler had entirely removed our `hi` section (`mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.L3` goes tiptoe to `L3` which corresponds to our `bye` section) and unfortunately decided that it's a good idea to increase `rsp` before a `ret` so to be sure we end up somewhere totally different where we need to be.

And clang delivers something even more dubious:

```
# else goto bye  is UNCOMMENTED
# clang -O1
fun:                                    # @fun
        mov     eax, 5
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     eax, 1
        call    rax
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        mov     esi, eax
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 66
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "TT: %d\n"
```

`1` ? How on earth did clang end up with this?

To some level I understand that the compiler decided that dead code after an `if` where both `if` and `else` go to the same location is not needed, but here my knowledge and insight stops.

So now, dear C and C++ gurus, assembly aficionados and compiler crushers, here comes the question:

Why?

Why do you think did the compiler decide that the two labels should be considered equivalent if we have added the `else` branch, or why did clang put there 1, and last but not least: someone with a deep understanding of the C standard could maybe point out where this piece of code deviated so badly from normality that we ended up in this really really weird situation.

Comment: I assume you're looking for something more thorough than "undefined behaviour makes optimizers do weird things."

Comment: @user253751 yeah, sort of ... :D

Comment: Who said that the label has to evaluate to the actual address of the code? I bet clang was going to generate a switch statement whenever you used computed goto.

Comment: What, which, where and when are all reasonable questions. Why is almost always a matter of opinions.

Comment: The standard doesn't have much to say about code that extensively messes with control flow using compiler extensions.  The best I can suggest is that you generate intermediate-representation dumps (for gcc, compile with `-fdump-tree-all -fdump-rtl-all` in addition to all other options; I don't remember offhand how to get the equivalent with clang) and then read through all of the files and figure out which optimizer did the Wrong Thing.  You can then ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` or the clang equivalent for an explanation of what the goal of that optimization is.

Comment: I would also like to point out that `asm ("ret")` is officially not supported; see the part of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html where it says "asm statements may not perform jumps [except to an explicit list of labels]".

Comment: If what you're actually trying to do is generate arbitrary function calls at run time, check out [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Is it C or C++? C++ has exception, C may or may not support exceptions/cancellation/stack unwinding. That may change stack layout and conventions.

Comment: `asm volatile ("movl $5, %eax");` is missing a clobber on EAX.  You step on the compiler's toes which is UB.  The use-case for GNU C Basic asm (no constraints / clobbers) is instructions like `cli` (disable interrupts), not anything involving integer registers.  But sure, if you want to throw arbitrary stuff into the compiler's asm output and see what happens, you can.  Just don't expect anything sensible.  Oh, but you're using this like a `__attribute__((naked))` function inside another function, not reached by normal execution.

Comment: You have a weird mix of AT&T and Intel syntax.  When Godbolt compiles for execution, it doesn't use `-masm=intel`; that's why your code assembles even though the output you copied has `movl $5, %eax` mixed with Intel syntax.

Comment: When you use `&&` on a label it is intended for goto's not to be cast to a function pointer and called as such. I'd venture to guess that the compilers optimizer realized that you never did an indirect or direct goto to the label `hi` in the case where you uncomment the `else` so it was removed as dead code. Calling a goto label as a function isn't defined behaviour so the compiler pretty much produced garbage.

Comment: My question is. What is it you are really trying to achieve? This seems like an XY problem. You are having us look at this as a solution to some problem, but I'd be want to ask what problem you are trying to solve in the first place and maybe we can help you find a better solution to that problem than the code you are using.

Comment: I don't recommend this at all, but you can trick the compiler into not optimizing away `hi` if you did something like use `asm goto` (if supported by the compiler) to jump to a label but obscure the actual path taken deating the optimizer. Change `if(c == 5) goto bye;
    else goto bye;` to `if(c == 5) asm goto ("jmp %l[bye]" :::: hi, bye);
    else goto bye;` . Although you tell the inline assembly the `hi` label is used, the compiler doesn't analyze the contents of the inline assembly to determine that to be the case so it assumes `hi` may be jumped to and it can't optimize that code away

Comment: But this is all a serious hack to do something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: You could in fact keep your code as is (the if/else statement) and defeat the optimizer from removing `hi` as dead code by putting this at the top of the function `asm goto ("" :::: hi);` . In that case you actually don't use `hi` as a target and the inline assembly does nothing with it, but it can't optimize `hi` away because the compiler doesn't try to determine what it is the inline assembly does or doesn't do. It will assume that you may be jumping to `hi` so it can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

> someone with a deep understanding of the C standard could maybe point out where this piece of code deviated so badly from normality that we ended up in this really really weird situation.

You think the ISO C standard has *anything* to say about this code?  It's chock full of UB and GNU extensions, notably pointers to local labels.

**Casting a label pointer to a function pointer and calling through it is obviously UB**.  The GCC manual doesn't say you can do that.  It's also UB to `goto` a label in another function.

You were only able to make that work by tricking the compiler into thinking that block might be reached so it's not removed, then using GNU C Basic `asm` statements to emit a `ret` instruction there.

GCC and clang remove dead code even with optimization disabled; e.g. `if(0) { ... }` doesn't emit any instructions to implement the `...`

Also note that the `c=5` in `hi:` compiles with optimization fully disabled (and `else goto bye` commented)  to asm like `movl    $5, -20(%rbp)`.  i.e. using the caller's RBP to modify local variables in the stack frame of the caller.  So you have a nested function.

GNU C allows you to [define nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) that can access the local vars of their parent scope.  (If you liked the asm you got from your experiment, you'll love the executable trampoline of machine-code that GCC stores to the stack with `mov`-immediate if you take a pointer to a nested function!)

---

`asm volatile ("movl $5, %eax");` is missing a clobber on EAX. You step on the compiler's toes which would be UB if this statement was ever reached normally, rather than as if it were a separate function.

The use-case for GNU C Basic asm (no constraints / clobbers) is instructions like `cli` (disable interrupts), not anything involving integer registers, and definitely not `ret`.

If you want to define a callable function using inline asm, you can use `asm("")` at global scope, or as the body of an `__attribute__((naked))` function.